# fading button transition is not working

Tags: html, css, button, css-transitions, fade

So I'm trying to emulate a button transition i have seen on a Google page I have tried all kinds of things to make the transition smooth but cannot get it to behave as smooth as its Google counter part. To be specific I want a smooth expansion of #fade_one that fills #button and a smooth fade out. So far I have not been able to achieve this through having simultaneous margin and width transitions, the timing on their respective ease-in and ease-out parameters does not seem to want to move in synchronization. Any help would be greatly appreciated! here is the Google link http://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/responsive-interaction.html#responsive-interaction-surface-response (scroll down to where is says "lift upon touch) and here is my fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/darth_business/hJchP/2/
Finally here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="button.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="button">
<div id="fade_one"></div>
<p id="button_text">Click Me</p>
</div> <!-- button ends -->
```

```
#button {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #5677fc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#button:hover #fade_one {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
#button_text {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 50px;
}
#fade_one {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 0px;
    margin: 0 0 0 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    -moz-transition: width .5s ease-in-out, opacity 1s ease-in;, margin .25s ease-in-out, opacity 1s ease-in;
}
```

Lastly I would like to mention that as much as possible I want to stay away from using java if i can, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is fundamentally about CSS positioning. The #fade_one element has absolute positioning. When you give you an element absolute position, it is taken out of the normal flow of the page and positioned **relative to its nearest positioned ancestor**.

In your case, you want the `#fade_one` element to be an overlay on top of the `#button` element. In other words, you want `#fade_one` to be positioned relative to `#button`. But in order for an absolute element to be relative to its ancestor, that ancestor needs to also be "positioned". The `#button` element is NOT positioned here.

So when the hover is triggered, the `#fade_one` element gets 100% width of its positioned ancestor -- which is not `#button`. In the fiddle, there is no positioned ancestor, so it takes the width of the `body` element.

The trick is to give a position to the ancestor element you want to contain the absolutely positioned child. Here, simply giving `#button` a relative position is enough to change it into the positioned ancestor for `#fade_one`.

Here's more on positioning:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning

I also took out margins as they are unnecessary. Try this CSS:

```
#button {
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #5677fc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;

}
#button:hover #fade_one {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#button_text {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 50px;
}
#fade_one {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 0px;
    left: 100px;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
       transition: left .5s ease-in-out, width .5s ease-in-out, opacity 1s ease-in, opacity 1s ease-in;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hJchP/11/

Comment: Although this is the exact thing I need I wonder if you would indulge me a little further, with the understanding that I have only begun programing seriously within last 6 months. I am interested to know what the difference was between declaring margin vs right and left and further what did the position relative change achieve? Thank you again for you help!

Comment: @user3791576 I took another look and my original explanation missed the mark (even though the CSS worked!). I edited the answer to address the real issue -- CSS positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Not as smooth as I would like it but this [codepen](http://codepen.io/joshhunt18/pen/lEmBx) should help you out. The essential part is to create a psuedo element and then animate it on hover. If you have any questions let me know.

**Code**

HTML

```
<div class="button">
    <span>
        Button
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS (not prefixed)

```
.button {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 12px 6px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}

.button:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background: #eee;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    transition: 0.2s;
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.button:hover:before {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.button span {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```